# UPDATE psql table with SELECT in json

Tags: json, postgresql, select, sql-update

Problem

```
column json
{"size": 120, "family": 5, "colour": 5552, "continent": 2, "animal_name": "Tiger"},
{"size": 200, "family": 5, "colour": 5552, "continent": 2, "animal_name": "Panda"},
{"size": 300, "family": 5, "colour": 5552, "continent": 2, "animal_name": "Lion"}


column name
default_animal
default_animal
default_animal
```

Solution

```
column name
Tiger
Panda
Lion
```

Description:

In TableName Animal, one column "json" contains all relevant data. (All available "animal_name")
But the column "name" should also contain the relevant animal_name - not "default_animal".

What's the most efficient way to solve this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE animals (id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,name TEXT,jsondata JSON);

INSERT INTO animals(name,jsondata) VALUES
    ('default_animal','{"size": 120, "family": 5, "colour": 5552, "continent": 2, "animal_name": "Tiger"}'::JSON),
    ('default_animal','{"size": 200, "family": 5, "colour": 5552, "continent": 2, "animal_name": "Panda"}'::JSON),
    ('default_animal','{"size": 300, "family": 5, "colour": 5552, "continent": 2, "animal_name": "Lion"}'::JSON)
;

UPDATE animals SET name = jsondata->>'animal_name' WHERE name = 'default_animal';
```

Comment: ```09:37:12 Kernel error: ERROR:  operator does not exist: text ->> unknown
```

Comment: which postgres version are you using? @Teletubbi-OSX I have tested it with postgres `9.4.4`. do you have `JSONB` column type ?

Comment: data_type = ```text```
OS X psql (9.4.4, server 9.3.4)

Comment: ```ALTER TABLE animals
ALTER COLUMN json TYPE JSONB USING json::JSONB;
```
leads to


```
Kernel error: ERROR:  type "jsonb" does not exist ```

Comment: @Teletubbi-OSX I have updated the answer for postgres v9.3.x(changed type from `JSONB` to `JSON`). `JSONB` was introduced in v9.4, that's why you were getting errors.

Comment: shutdown 9.3.4 was one prerequisite! ;)
Thank you, your approach works perfect!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that column json contains exactly one instance of Animal the the following approach should work:

update Animal set name = substring(json position("animal_name" in json) + 15  char_length(json) - 2  )